# fabric-ca-server connect to azure mysql: this authentication plugin is not supported

Tags: mysql, azure, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am baffled why I am unable to start the fabric-ca-server using azure's MySql database, I keep on getting `this authentication plugin is not supported`

Using the exact same connectionstring in a simple go script works:

```
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", sqlConnString)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer db.Close()
    rows, err := db.Query(sqlString)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    columns, err := rows.Columns()
    ...
```

However starting the fabric-ca-server with:

```
fabric-ca-server start --db.datasource="user@server:pw@tcp(server.mysql.database.azure.com:3306)/fabricca?parseTime=true&allowNativePasswords=true" --db.type=mysql -b admin:admin
```

Results in the error:

```
2019/08/07 23:39:35 [DEBUG] Initializing DB
2019/08/07 23:39:35 [DEBUG] Initializing 'mysql' database at '****:****@tcp(server.mysql.database.azure.com:3306)/fabricca?parseTime=true'
2019/08/07 23:39:35 [DEBUG] Using MySQL database, connecting to database...
2019/08/07 23:39:35 [DEBUG] Database Name: fabricca
2019/08/07 23:39:35 [DEBUG] Connecting to MySQL server, using connection string: ****:****@tcp(server.mysql.database.azure.com:3306)/?parseTime=true
2019/08/07 23:39:35 [ERROR] Error occurred initializing database: Failed to connect to MySQL database: this authentication plugin is not supported
```

I have tried with the following versions, same results

- 1.4.0
- 1.4.1
- 1.4.2

With the following parameters:

- < none >
- ?parseTime=true
- ?parseTime=true&allowNativePasswords=true

The mysql server is of version 5.7

I have tried creating the database before hand and starting without an existing database

I have tried with an admin user, a specific user with all grants for the selected database

I tried creating users with a different password plugins (defaults to mysql_native_password on azure mysql 5.7)

However the error keeps popping up.
There does not seem to be anything wrong with the connection string as I can use it in other go scripts without any issues.

Tried it with tls & without tls. The only difference I can see that is being used is: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca/blob/477f5a2e8200232a50a3751976f6fa3d3f9062c9/lib/server/db/mysql/mysql.go#L66

Did anyone encounter this issue before, or know what is going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like we are still using a very old version of the mysql driver which did not support authentication plugins at all.  I assume your sample code pulled down a more recent version of the driver.

Comment: Just pushed a fix as well

Comment: Code is now merged ... you can clone the release-1.4 branch and build the executables and/or Docker images and hopefully your issue should be fixed

Comment: This will be officially available in docker version 1.4.3 and above ?

Comment: Yeah ... 1.4.3 and also 2.0.0 later this year

Comment: Thanks for the quick response